# Hadoop Yarn Container Does Not Allocate Enough Space

Tags: hadoop

I'm running a Hadoop job, and in my yarn-site.xml file, I have the following configuration:

```
    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>2048</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>4096</value>
    </property>
```

However, I still occasionally get the following error:

```
Container [pid=63375,containerID=container_1388158490598_0001_01_000003] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 2.0 GB of 2 GB physical memory used; 2.8 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

I've found that by increasing yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb, the physical memory allocated for the container goes up. However, I don't always want 4GB being allocated for my container, and thought that by explicitly specifying a maximum size, I'd be able to go around this problem. I realize that Hadoop can't figure out how much memory it needs to allocate for the container before the mapper runs, so how should I go about allocating more memory for the container only if it needs that extra memory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should also properly configure the memory allocations for MapReduce. From [this HortonWorks tutorial](http://hortonworks.com/blog/how-to-plan-and-configure-yarn-in-hdp-2-0/):

> [...]
>
> For our example cluster, we have the minimum RAM for a Container
>   (yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb) = 2 GB. We’ll thus assign 4 GB
>   for Map task Containers, and 8 GB for Reduce tasks Containers.
>
> In mapred-site.xml:
>
> `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`: 4096
>
> `mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb`: 8192
>
> Each Container will run JVMs for the Map and Reduce tasks. The JVM
>   heap size should be set to lower than the Map and Reduce memory
>   defined above, so that they are within the bounds of the Container
>   memory allocated by YARN.
>
> In mapred-site.xml:
>
> `mapreduce.map.java.opts`: `-Xmx3072m`
>
> `mapreduce.reduce.java.opts`: `-Xmx6144m`
>
> The above settings **configure the upper limit of the physical RAM that
>   Map and Reduce tasks will use**.

Finally, someone in [this thread in the Hadoop mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-hdfs-user/201312.mbox/%3CCA+JstLAu9LfHN-B9zLazpm9CXH-iMtqA56oP_WD8OhBM8uFqRw@mail.gmail.com%3E) had the same problem and in their case, it turned out they had a memory leak in their code.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what should be the 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' 'yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores' 'mapreduce.task.timeout' 'mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb' with your above example

Answer (score 0):

If any of the above configurations didn't help. If the issue is related to mapper memory, couple of things I would like to suggest that needs to be checked are.

- Check if **combiner is enabled or not**? If yes, then it means that reduce logic has to be run on all the records (output of mapper). **This happens in memory.** Based on your application you need to check if enabling combiner helps or not. Trade off is between the network transfer bytes and time taken/memory/CPU for the reduce logic on 'X' number of records.

  - If you feel that combiner is not much of value, just disable it.
  - If you need combiner and 'X' is a huge number (say millions of records) then considering changing your split logic (For default input formats use less block size, normally 1 block size = 1 split) to map less number of records to a single mapper.
- Number of records getting processed in a single mapper. Remember that all these records need to be sorted **in memory** (output of mapper is sorted). Consider setting **mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb**  (default is 200MB) to a higher value if needed. [mapred-configs.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)
- If any of the above didn't help, try to run the mapper logic as a standalone application and profile the application using a Profiler (like JProfiler) and see where the memory getting used. This can give you very good insights.