# hive job stuck at map=100%, reduce 0%

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm running hive-0.12.0 on hadoop-2.2.0.  After submitting the query:

```
select  i_item_desc
  ,i_category
  ,i_class
  ,i_current_price
  ,i_item_id
  ,sum(ws_ext_sales_price) as itemrevenue
  ,sum(ws_ext_sales_price)*100/sum(sum(ws_ext_sales_price)) over
      (partition by i_class) as revenueratio
from item JOIN web_sales ON (web_sales.ws_item_sk = item.i_item_sk) JOIN date_dim ON (web_sales.ws_sold_date_sk = date_dim.d_date_sk)
where item.i_category in ('Jewelry', 'Sports', 'Books')
    and date_dim.d_date between '2001-01-12' and '2001-02-11'
    and ws_sold_date between '2001-01-12' and '2001-02-11'
group by
    i_item_id
    ,i_item_desc
    ,i_category
    ,i_class
    ,i_current_price
order by
    i_category
    ,i_class
    ,i_item_id
    ,i_item_desc
    ,revenueratio
limit 100;
```

I get the following errors in the logs:

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-3: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2014-07-07 15:26:16,893 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-07-07 15:26:22,033 Stage-3 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.32 sec
```

And then the last line repeats every second or so ad infinitum.  If I look at container logs I see:

```
2014-07-07 17:12:17,477 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1404402886929_0036_m_000000_0: Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
```

I've searched for the Exit code 143, but most the stuff out there refers to memory issue and I have memory set pretty large  (following the advice of [Container is running beyond memory limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005643/container-is-running-beyond-memory-limits)).  I have even tried adding 6GB to each of the settings in that post, still no luck.

I've also run the job with:

```
hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

which really just produces alot more info, but nothing I see makes clear what the issue is.

I'm not sure where else to look...

Comment: What is the query you executed ?

Comment: oops.  fixed now.  thanks.

Comment: running into it again on hadoop 2.3.0