# Spark - Container is running beyond physical memory limits

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a cluster of two worker nodes. 
Worker_Node_1 - 64GB RAM
Worker_Node_2 - 32GB RAM

**Background Summery :**
I am trying to execute spark-submit on yarn-cluster to run Pregel on a Graph to calculate the shortest path distances from one source vertex to all other vertices and print the values on console. 
Experment :

1. For Small graph with 15 vertices execution completes application final status : SUCCEEDED
2. My code works perfectly and prints shortest distance for 241 vertices graph for single vertex as source vertex but there is a problem.

**Problem :**
When I dig into the Log file the task gets complete **successfully** in 4 mins and 26 Secs but still on the terminal it keeps on showing application status as **Running** and after approx 12 more minutes task execution terminates saying -

```
Application application_1447669815913_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1447669815913_0002_000002 exited with exitCode: -104 For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://myserver.com:8088/proxy/application_1447669815913_0002/
Then, click on links to logs of each attempt. 
Diagnostics: Container [pid=47384,containerID=container_1447669815913_0002_02_000001] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 17.9 GB of 17.5 GB physical memory used; 18.7 GB of 36.8 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.

Dump of the process-tree for container_1447669815913_0002_02_000001 : 
 |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
|- 47387 47384 47384 47384 (java) 100525 13746 20105633792 4682973 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-cloudera/bin/java -server -Xmx16384m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/yarn/nm/usercache/cloudera/appcache/application_1447669815913_0002/container_1447669815913_0002_02_000001/tmp -Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true -Dspark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://myserver.com:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory -Dspark.executor.memory=14g -Dspark.shuffle.service.enabled=false -Dspark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 -Dspark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://myserver.com:18088 -Dspark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native -Dspark.shuffle.service.port=7337 -Dspark.yarn.jar=local:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly.jar -Dspark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer -Dspark.authenticate=false -Dspark.app.name=com.path.PathFinder -Dspark.master=yarn-cluster -Dspark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native -Dspark.yarn.am.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1447669815913_0002/container_1447669815913_0002_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class com.path.PathFinder --jar file:/home/cloudera/Documents/Longest_Path_Data_1/Jars/ShortestPath_Loop-1.0.jar --arg /home/cloudera/workspace/Spark-Integration/LongestWorstPath/configFile --executor-memory 14336m --executor-cores 32 --num-executors 2
|- 47384 47382 47384 47384 (bash) 2 0 17379328 853 /bin/bash -c LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native::/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-cloudera/bin/java -server -Xmx16384m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/yarn/nm/usercache/cloudera/appcache/application_1447669815913_0002/container_1447669815913_0002_02_000001/tmp '-Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true' '-Dspark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://myserver.com:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory' '-Dspark.executor.memory=14g' '-Dspark.shuffle.service.enabled=false' '-Dspark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048' '-Dspark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://myserver.com:18088' '-Dspark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native' '-Dspark.shuffle.service.port=7337' '-Dspark.yarn.jar=local:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly.jar' '-Dspark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer' '-Dspark.authenticate=false' '-Dspark.app.name=com.path.PathFinder' '-Dspark.master=yarn-cluster' '-Dspark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native' '-Dspark.yarn.am.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1447669815913_0002/container_1447669815913_0002_02_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class 'com.path.PathFinder' --jar file:/home/cloudera/Documents/Longest_Path_Data_1/Jars/ShortestPath_Loop-1.0.jar --arg '/home/cloudera/workspace/Spark-Integration/LongestWorstPath/configFile' --executor-memory 14336m --executor-cores 32 --num-executors 2 1> /var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1447669815913_0002/container_1447669815913_0002_02_000001/stdout 2> /var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1447669815913_0002/container_1447669815913_0002_02_000001/stderr
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

**Things I tried :**

1. yarn.schedular.maximum-allocation-mb – 32GB
2. mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 2048 (Previously it was 1024)
3. Tried varying --driver-memory upto 24g

Could you please put more color on to how I can configure the Resource Manager so that Large Size Graphs ( > 300K vertices) can also be processed? Thanks.

Comment: There's a previous similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005643/container-is-running-beyond-memory-limits

Comment: @aditya did you find anything ? the other didn't help me

Comment: You need to fine tune your application with the cluster's capacity. Params --driver-memory --executor-memory --executor-cores --num-executors play a very important role while you do spark-submit on yarn-cluster.

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html please go through this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anybody know how can I understand which operation is going OutOfMemory? If it is some join or if it is some cached data? Thanks!

Comment: Any solution to this issue? , I am facing same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209905/spark-application-throws-container-physical-memory-error

Answer (score 4):

Just increase default conf of `spark.driver.memory` from `512m` to `2g` solve this error in my case.

You may set the memory to higher if it keeps hitting the same error. Then, you can keep reducing it until it hits the same error so that you know the optimum driver memory to use for your job.

Answer (score 3):

The more data you are processing, the more memory is needed by each Spark task. And if your executor is running too many tasks then it can run out of memory. When I had problems processing large amounts of data, it usually was a result of not properly balancing the number of cores per executor. Try to either reduce the number of cores or increase the executor memory.

One easy way to tell that you are having memory issues is to check the Executor tab on the Spark UI. If you see a lot of red bars indicating high garbage collection time, you are probably running out of memory in your executors.

Comment: He said the __Container__ is running out of memory _not_ the executor

Answer (score 2):

I slove the error in my case to increase conf of **spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead** Which stand for off-heap memory
When you increase the amount of driver-memory and executor-memory, do not forget this config item

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem :

Key error info:

- **exitCode: -104**
- **'PHYSICAL' memory limit**

```
Application application_1577148289818_10686 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1577148289818_10686_000002 exited with **exitCode: -104**

Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2019-12-26 09:13:54.392]Container [pid=18968,containerID=container_e96_1577148289818_10686_02_000001] is running 132722688B beyond the **'PHYSICAL' memory limit**. Current usage: 1.6 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used; 4.6 GB of 3.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

Increase both `spark.executor.memory` and `spark.executor.memoryOverhead` didn't take effect .

Then I increase `spark.driver.memory` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Spark jobs ask for resources from resource manager in a different way from MapReduce jobs. Try to tune the number of executors and mem/vcore allocated to each executor. Follow http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html