# Giraph Example ShortestPathComputation reports FAILED state

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, shortest-path, giraph, bigdata

I have installed and deployed giraph-1.1.0 using the hadoop yarn profile with the following command

```
mvn -Phadoop_yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -DskipTests clean package
```

From the folder giraph-examples/target I tried running the ShortestPathsComputation example thus

```
hadoop jar giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation \
-vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat \ 
-vip /user/$USER/input/testgraph.txt \
-vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat \
-op /user/$USER/output/shortestpaths -w 1 
-yj giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get the following error when I run

> ERROR yarn.GiraphYarnClient: Giraph:
>   org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation reports
>   FAILED state, diagnostics show: Application
>   application_1471411023577_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for
>   appattempt_1471411023577_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: -103
>   Diagnostics: Container
>   [pid=30415,containerID=container_1471411023577_0001_02_000001] is
>   running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 273.2 MB of 1 GB
>   physical memory used; 2.3 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing
>   container.

Do I need to rebuild giraph or does the problem lie elsewhere?

Comment: Looks like you ran out of memory - `Container is running beyond virtual memory limits` - take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005643/container-is-running-beyond-memory-limits

Comment: Thank you @Binary Nerd. That worked.