# Spark Memory error

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting the below error in Spark 1.5 :

```
 Diagnostics: Container [pid=19554,containerID=container_e94_1518800506024_42837_02_000017] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 3.5 GB of 3.5 GB physical memory used; 4.3 GB of 7.3 GB virtual memory used. Killing container. Dump of the process-tree for container_e94_1518800506024_42837_02_000017
```

> MASTER_URL=yarn-cluster
>
> NUM_EXECUTORS=10
>
> EXECUTOR_MEMORY=4G
>
> EXECUTOR_CORES=6
>
> DRIVER_MEMORY=3G

The data the application reads is 7MB of avro file, but there are multiple writes in spark application.

Is there any problem with Job configuration ?

Comment: If possible, try increasing executors' memory. There's also probably a memory intensive action in your code which could be improved.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: It is big application , I wont able to share the code, It reads a 7MB input file and does some filters and joins and then stores output in 32 HDFS dirs. one by one . It stores into 32 dirs. because there are 32 partitions are there in the final dataframe .

Comment: Where is your spark cluster running? Yarn? Local? Kubernetes?

Comment: It is yarn which is allocating resources and this spark application is running Hadoop cluster , cloudera CD5.5 (Hadoop 2.x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Container is running beyond memory limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005643/container-is-running-beyond-memory-limits)