# Hadoop Containder is running beyond physical memory limits

Tags: hadoop

While running Hadoop task, I got the following error

```
Container [pid=12850,containerID=container_1489504424139_0638_01_201123] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 4.0 GB of 4 GB physical memory used; 8.8 GB of 8.4 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

I searched in stackoverflow, it gives me several pages([Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803577/hadoop-yarn-container-does-not-allocate-enough-space/), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005643/container-is-running-beyond-memory-limits)). But it does not help. I still got the error. My current `mapred-site.xml` file is the following:

```xml
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value> -Xmx3072m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
  <value> -Xmx6144m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
  <value>4096</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
  <value>8192</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx2048m</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried changed the xml files. But later I found if I make my python code ( it is building object through some java api which depends on some C++ api ) more memory-friendly, i.e. if it's out of scope, then I call its destructor explicitly. Then the problem is gone!

Answer (score 1):

Try using these properties :

```
mapreduce.map.output.compress
mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec
```

OR

Changing the memory allocation props:

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb
mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb
```